# Sort MySql query by field in exists sub query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for a way to sort a query by a field that exists within a where  exists query.
An attempt to use a field from the exists subquery I get the 'Unknown column' error.
Example query;

```
select
    *
from
    `table_a`
where
    `a_field` = 'foo'
    and exists (
            select
                *
            from
                `table_b`
            where
                `table_a`.`an_id` = `table_b`.`another_id` and `table_b`.`another_field` = 'bar'
        )
order by
    `table_a`.`created_at` asc,
    `table_b`.`another_id` desc;
```

Is the only solution to use an inner join query like;

```
select
    `t1`.*
from
    `table_a` as `t1`
    inner join `table_2` as `t2` on `t2`.`another_id` = `t1`.`an_id`
where
    `t1`.`a_field` = 'foo'
    and `t2`.`another_field` = 'bar'
order by
    `t1`.`created_at` asc,
    `t2`.`another_id` desc;
```

Comment: What's wrong with your solution?

Comment: If the column you are using in sorting is not in the `table_a`, then yes, you need to do a JOIN. The tables from subqueries are not visible in top level. (In the first example you could also sort by `table_a.an_id` as it's the same as the `table_b.another_id`)

Comment: @Strawberry nothing is wrong, just curiosity if it could be done. The answer may well be 'no'.

Comment: The answer is rarely 'no', but it's often 'why'

Comment: @Strawberry why; in my real world example the exists query performs quicker, and rather then blindly go back to what I have always done just wanted to check is there was another way.

Comment: 'Is the only solution to use an inner join query like;' - sql (of any dialect) mechanisms for getting data from multiple table are JOIN,UNION and correlated sub query. In your case inner join seems appropriate and if slow check your indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Your example query is ordering by `another_id`, which is used in the correlation clause.  So, you can just do:

```
select a.*
from table_a a
where a.a_field = 'foo' and
      exists (select 1
              from table_b b
              where a.an_id = b.another_id and
                    b.another_field = 'bar'
             )
order by a.created_at asc,
         a.an_id desc;
```

Assuming you actually want a *different* column, you can use a `JOIN`.  The issue is that more than one row may match.  So you need to remove the duplicates in the subquery:

```
select a.*
from table_a a join
     (select b.another_id, max(b.another_col) as another_col
      from table_b b
      where another_field = 'bar'
      group by b.another_id
     ) b
     on a.an_id = b.another_id
where a.a_field = 'foo'
order by a.created_at asc, b.another_id desc;
```

You can only use your form of the `JOIN` if you know that at most one row will match.